# How to position StaticLayout in android?

Tags: android, drawtext

I want to created a wrapping text ontop of google maps api.  I have been able to do this with a lot of code, but have been working on a better way.  My latest attempt is to use the StaticLayout class and the text is wrapping, but I do not know how to position it...no matter what I try it is always starting in the top left corner of the screen....

Answer (score 14):

try doing a `canvas.translate(x,y)` before you call `draw(c)` on the layout.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it as follows

```
//Save canvas before translating it, otherwise restore will cause crash (Underflow in restore - more restores than saves)
canvas.save()

canvas.translate(xPos, yPos);
statictextlayout.draw(canvas);

//After that to reset the canvas back for everything else
canvas.restore();
```

To continue drawing normally afterwards... call canvas.restore() after you staticlayout draw and you should be good to continue drawing on you canvas.

Comment: canvas.save() needs to be called before calling canvas.restore().

It seems to work like push() / pop()